# how to combine multiple foreach in single echo?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, foreach

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';  
// Create DOM from URL 
$html = file_get_html('http://some site. com/'); ?>

<?php
foreach($html->find('a.cellMainLink') as $title) 
echo '<div class="title"><table class="title" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$title->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>'; 
?>

<?php 
    foreach($html->find('td.nobr') as $size)
    echo '<div class="size"><table class="size" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td>'.$size.'</td></tr></table></div>'; 
    ?>

<?php 
foreach($html->find('td.green') as $seeds) 
echo '<div class="seeds"><table class="seeds" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr> <td>'.$seeds.'</td></tr></table></div>'; ?>

<?php 
foreach($html->find('td.red') as $leechs) 
echo '<div class="leechs"><table class="leechs" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr> <td>'.$leechs.'</td></tr></table></div>'; ?>

<?php 
foreach($html->find('strong a[1]') as $category) 
echo '<div class="cat"><table class="cat" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>'.$category->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>'; ?>

<?php 
foreach($html->find('a[class=idownload icon16]') as $down) 
echo '<div style="font-size:12px">'.$down->href.'</div><br />'; ?>
```

right now the result in multiple echos.. i want all these results in one echo and then i will store the result into my database..

Comment: take one variable $html and  append all value with "." 

$html .='<div style="font-size:12px">'.$down->href.'</div><br />';
in each loop

Comment: Start removing the `?>  <?php` constructions, it wont fix your problems but it makes your code readable and less error prone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.=`, in a php variable. It is the concatenating assignment operator.

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';  // Create DOM from URL 
$html = file_get_html('http://some site. com/');
$what_you_echo = "";
?>

<?php
foreach($html->find('a.cellMainLink') as $title) 
 $what_you_echo .= '<div class="title"><table class="title" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$title->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>'; 
?>

<?php 
    foreach($html->find('td.nobr') as $size)
    $what_you_echo .= '<div class="size"><table class="size" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td>'.$size.'</td></tr></table></div>'; 
    ?>

<?php 
foreach($html->find('td.green') as $seeds) 
$what_you_echo .=  '<div class="seeds"><table class="seeds" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr> <td>'.$seeds.'</td></tr></table></div>'; ?>

<?php 
foreach($html->find('td.red') as $leechs) 
$what_you_echo .=  '<div class="leechs"><table class="leechs" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr> <td>'.$leechs.'</td></tr></table></div>'; ?>

<?php 
foreach($html->find('strong a[1]') as $category) 
$what_you_echo .=  '<div class="cat"><table class="cat" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>'.$category->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>'; ?>

<?php 
foreach($html->find('a[class=idownload icon16]') as $down) 
$what_you_echo .=  '<div style="font-size:12px">'.$down->href.'</div><br />'; ?>

<?php echo $what_you_echo; ?>
```

You can style your code, by removing these lots of `<?php`:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';  // Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://some site. com/');
$what_you_echo = "";

foreach($html->find('a.cellMainLink') as $title) 
$what_you_echo .= '<div class="title"><table class="title" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td style="font-size:12px;">'.$title->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>'; 

foreach($html->find('td.nobr') as $size)
$what_you_echo .= '<div class="size"><table class="size" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>'.$size.'</td></tr></table></div>'; 

foreach($html->find('td.green') as $seeds) 
$what_you_echo .=  '<div class="seeds"><table class="seeds" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr> <td>'.$seeds.'</td></tr></table></div>';

foreach($html->find('td.red') as $leechs) 
$what_you_echo .=  '<div class="leechs"><table class="leechs" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr> <td>'.$leechs.'</td></tr></table></div>';

foreach($html->find('strong a[1]') as $category) 
$what_you_echo .=  '<div class="cat"><table class="cat" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td>'.$category->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>';

foreach($html->find('a[class=idownload icon16]') as $down) 
$what_you_echo .=  '<div style="font-size:12px">'.$down->href.'</div><br />';

echo $what_you_echo; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable, and append the values.

```
<?php
$out = '';
include 'simple_html_dom.php'; 
// Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://some site. com/');
foreach ($html->find('a.cellMainLink') as $title) {
    $out .= '<div class="title"><table class="title" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$title->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>';
}
foreach ($html->find('td.nobr') as $size) {
    $out .= '<div class="size"><table class="size" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td>'.$size.'</td></tr></table></div>';
}
foreach ($html->find('td.green') as $seeds) {
    $out .= '<div class="seeds"><table class="seeds" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td>'.$seeds.'</td></tr></table></div>';
}
foreach ($html->find('td.red') as $leechs) {
    $out .= '<div class="leechs"><table class="leechs" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td>'.$leechs.'</td></tr></table></div>';
}
foreach ($html->find('strong a[1]') as $category) {
    $out .= '<div class="cat"><table class="cat" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td>'.$category->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>';
}
foreach ($html->find('a[class=idownload icon16]') as $down) {
    $out .= '<div style="font-size:12px">'.$down->href.'</div><br />';
}
echo $out;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe this?:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';  // Create DOM from URL
$html = file_get_html('http://some site. com/');

$el_arr['a.cellMainLink'] = $html->find('a.cellMainLink');
$el_arr['td.nobr'] = $html->find('td.nobr');
$el_arr['td.green'] = $html->find('td.green');
$el_arr['td.red'] = $html->find('td.red');
$el_arr['strong [1]'] = $html->find('strong [1]');
$el_arr['a[class=idownload icon16]'] = $html->find('a[class=idownload icon16]');
foreach($el_arr as $key=>$el)
{
 foreach($el as $node)
 {
  //echo your content accordingly here using $key and $node
  //$key represent the type of element and $node represent a node of that type from html
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

creat a php array and put the results of each echo in this array and after echo the array 
 exemple:

```
 <?php
    $results=array[];
    $our_var='';
    foreach($html->find('a.cellMainLink') as $title)
{ 
    $our_var='<div class="title"><table class="title" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
        <td style="font-size:12px;">'.$title->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>';
    array_push($results,$our_var); 
}
    ?>
```

do this to the others and after play with your array as you wish

Answer (score 0):

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';  // Create DOM from URL 
$html = file_get_html('http://some site. com/');
$what_you_echo = "";

foreach($html->find('a.cellMainLink') as $title) 
    echo  '<div class="title"><table class="title" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td style="font-size:12px;">'.$title->plaintext.'</td></tr></table></div>'; 
    $size = current($html->find('td.nobr'));
    echo '<div class="size"><table class="size" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr>
    <td>'.$size.'</td></tr></table></div>'; 
    next($html->find('td.nobr'));
```

how about this